# Unchecked Cast from Class<capture#2-of ?> to Class<? extends EntityGhost>

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, minecraft

So, I was recently trying to fix some things in my code. I do Minecraft Modding in eclipse and found that some of the things in the code were unchecked. I couldn't find a solution to this one because nothing had been programmed similarly or exactly in this way, making it difficult to find out what to change in the code.

```
this.ghostTypes.add((Class<? extends EntityGhost>) Class.forName(types.getStringTagAt(i)));
```

if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I've been searching high and low on google but nothing was found except some people having the same problem, but completely different code.

Comment: *"I couldn't find a solution"* Well, what is the problem you're trying to solve? It's a **warning**, not an error. The code compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is telling you that there is no way of knowing what exactly what class `Class.forName` will return. It might not be a match for `Class<? extends EntityGhost>`.

So there is no way that the cast can be checked by the compiler. If `Class.forName` returns something that does not match you will an error at runtime.

The message is only a warning to tell you about this. You can suppress the message using

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```